# This is the code for my "bag" or inventory command

Tags: python, json, discord.py

```py
@client.command()
async def bag(ctx):
    await open_account(ctx.author)
    user = ctx.author
    users = await get_bank_data()
    
    try:
        bag = users[str(user.id)]["bag"]
    except:
        bag = []


    em = discord.Embed(title = "Bag")
    for item in bag:
        name = item["item"]
        amount = item["amount"]

        em.add_field(name = name, value = amount)    

    await ctx.send(embed = em)
```

So i want to check if there is a specific item in the bag. Suppose the item name is "common", how would i do that? Ive tried numerous for item in bag and stuff like that but none work!

Comment: please help me, I need help

Comment: Dear OP, i am reviewer, see how to ask questions here.

Comment: @SunderamDubey Helpful link related to your comment: [ask]

Comment: help me please, I need help, it's urgent

Comment: Please show your error code and the problem you face here. We are willing to help you but we can't understand what you meant. Sorry to tell you **we can't read your mind.** [ask]

Comment: there is no error

Comment: I want to make a economy bot fish command discord.py, so how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to check if there is an item in the list you could just do this:

```py
@client.command()
async def bag(ctx):
    await open_account(ctx.author)
    user = ctx.author
    users = await get_bank_data()
    
    try:
        bag = users[str(user.id)]["bag"]
    except:
        bag = []


    em = discord.Embed(title = "Bag")
    for item in bag:
        name = item["item"]
        amount = item["amount"]

        em.add_field(name = name, value = amount)

    for item in bag:
        if name == "common":
            #do stuff  

    await ctx.send(embed = em)
```